# How can i query more than 5000 documents from a collection using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query more than 5000 documents at a time and i wanted to ask how can i implement pagination in this so i can query more than 5000 documents at a time.i am unable to find any solution regarding this.how can i write the pagination code to fetch more than 5000 documents at a time

```
const querysnapshot = await db.collection('xyz').limit(5000).get();
```

using this i am able to  get the 5000 documents but after that i am unable to get that's why i am trying to use pagination

Comment: Write "**more than 5000 documents at a time**" once is completely enough. Did you already fetch the data and just want to implement pagination?

Comment: @Buczkowski i have a collection where more than 5000 documents are available and i want to query all the data at once and there is a limit to fetch only 5000 documents at one go

Comment: can you show what you have so far?

Comment: @Buczkowski i have updated the query and i have tried the documentation pagination query but unable to perform that's why i am asking for help

Comment: Next question would be if you want to implement your pagination from scratch or use exisiting solution like paginator-js or pagination.js (or at least create your version based on those solutions).

Comment: @Buczkowski i am unable to figure out that's why i am asking. can you  help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you try the approach that is described in the [documentation on pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes i have tried but haven't got the response

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried, following the guidance on [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without such an MCVE it is unlikely that we can help you better than what the documentation does.

Comment: I agree with Frank, you question is not clear and is lacking of information on what did you already tried. Please edit your question because right now isn't clear why the approach form the public documentation is not working for you